# "Виден блеск вероломной родины..."? Как выкрутиться, если смысл прозрачен?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

> Азоло славен тем, что здесь была заточена королева Венеции. Вот прямо
>   в этой высокой башне. Из окна ей в ясную погоду был виден блеск
>   вероломной родины. А еще сюда удалилась, когда ушла со сцены, великая
>   театральная актриса начала ХХ века – Элеонора Дузе.

Даю расширенный контекст сознательно.

И - можно ли сохранить тире перед Элеонорой Дузе?

Comment: На что была "затОчена" королева Венеции - на правление? Насильно затачивали, ибо отказывалась править? :) Заточают же скорее "куда", а не "где". Пребывала она в заточении, будучи заточённой "сюда".

Comment: Тире можно сохранить, если цепь регалий перед именем сделать уникальной (по которой её знающие люди узнали бы, напр. "великая... века с разного цвета глазами" - как у Дэвида Боуи).

Comment: Саша, не ёрничай! В башне заточАют, а не затАчивают!

Comment: В башнЮ - словари так предлагают управлять.

Comment: Лжец нищасный! *Заточить в монастырь. Заточить в тюрьму.* https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/813898 *З. в крепость. З. в одиночной камере.* http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x

Comment: Изначально «Дож — титул главы государства в итальянских морских республиках — Венецианской, Генуэзской и Амальфийской».

Comment: "Грамота" сама же оправдывается за тот сиротливо-толковый словарь - при каких доп. условиях возможно "где": 2. где (-> место действия, при наличии уточняющего обстоятельства). Заточить _в тюрьме_ в одиночную камер**у**. Стало быть, заточить _в камере_ можно только в сундук!

Comment: Азоло как город, конечно, годится на _место действия_ (где), а вот башня - нет. У Даля, который не даст испортить даже ударение в слове "творОг", заточают "куда и кого", про место случившегося заточения куда-л. тоже говорится отдельно, чтобы не путали _меру_ пресечения с _местом_ его же.

Comment: Саш, на самом деле я тебе благодарна. Но - вот зачем два примера управления в один объединять? И Академик тож...

Comment: Я по невежеству своему сначала подумал, что Азоло - замок. Может, когда-то так и было? В "академике" же начинается с цитирования вполне авторитетного Ушакова (помладше Даля) - там только "куда-нибудь".

Answer (score 2):

Сочетание "вероломная родина" можно рассматривать как **оксюморон** (совмещение несочетаемых понятий). Индивидуально-авторские оксюмороны встречаются часто (сладкий яд, прекрасно болен).

Тире не нужно,  в начала ХХ века были и другие великие актрисы.

Comment: С родиной (где родилась и росла) - не так плохо сочетается, вот если бы "вероломная Отчизна"... Больше вопросов вызывает "блеск вероломства" этой самой родины. Да и некоторые виды ядов (напр. с наполнителем) реально сладки на вкус

Comment: Да, с блеском не всё понятно, может быть,  контекст как-то  его разъясняет.

Comment: Ну да, есть сладкий яд, например: "О, сладкий яд любви, тебя я пить готов".  Метафора, конечно, но всё-таки...

Comment: Распутину он был сладок в пирожных, но есть и сами по себе такие яды: _Яд сей [из слюны отравленного кабана] имеет сладковатый вкус и называется кантарелла_ (Е. Арсеньева, "Государева невеста")

Comment: У Распутина с этим ядом не поймешь, что было: то ли его не положил врач-гуманист, то ли он был некачественный, то ли сахар в принципе нейтрализует цианистый калий (в сладкую мадеру и пирожные класть нельзя). А может, старец "приучил" себя к ядам заранее.